# Html reporting solutions for Specflow using NUnit

Tags: specflow

I am setting up a c# BDD Test automation framework using the following basic components:

Specflow
NUnit / SpecRun (test runner - see below)
Selenium

I have successfully set up a framework which executes tests and generates a nice HTML report (to do this, I used SpecRun as the test runner.. http://www.specflow.org/plus/runner/).

I am now trying to set my tests up to execute in Sauce labs to do cross-browser and device testing.  Jenkins has a nice Sauce plugin which allows you to specify the platforms and the tests are then run across each selected platform.

I have also identified Saucery (http://fullcirclesolutions.com.au/) as a potential time saver in setting this integration up, however, this would mean that I would need to use NUnit as my test runner instead of Specrun.

If I am to go down the NUnit route, does anyone know of any decent html reporting solutions which I can integrate into the test run.  A lot of googling has returned very little in the way of answers here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `specflow.exe` program to create reports, it comes with the specflow package. How it works in detail can be found on the [specflow github](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Reporting). Summarized:

> In order to generate this report you have to execute the acceptance
>   tests with the nunit-console runner. This tool generates an XML
>   summary about the test executions. To have the detailed scenario
>   execution traces visible, you also need to capture the test output
>   using the /out and the /labels options as it can be seen in the
>   following example.
>
> ```
> nunit-console.exe /labels /out=TestResult.txt 
>     /xml=TestResult.xml bin\Debug\BookShop.AcceptanceTests.dll
> ```
>
> The two generated files can be
>   used to invoke the SpecFlow report generation. If you use the output
>   file names shown above it is enough to specify the project file path
>   containing the feature files.
>
> ```
> specflow.exe nunitexecutionreport BookShop.AcceptanceTests.csproj
>     /out:MyResult.html
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Allure.

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2

NUnit, Specflow, any framework